# Uniform convergence of series $\sum (-1)^n f_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Check the uniform convergence of the series $$\sum (-1)^n  f_n(x)$$
where $$f_n(x) = \ln \left( 1+ \frac{x}{n(1+x)} \right)$$

Do i need to sum them two-by-two and obtain something neat?

Also why does the last inequality here
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130031/45470
hold? If so, can i make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach. You can use [Dirichlet's Test for Uniform Convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence). In your case take

> $$a_n(x)=(-1)^n\,\quad  b_n(x) = \ln\left( 1+\frac{x}{n(1+x)}\right). $$

Comment: But this is for series with positive terms, no?

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski: See what I added.

Answer (score 2):

By summing them two-by-two we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n f_n(x) &=& \sum_{m\geq 1}\log\left(\frac{2m+(2m+1)x}{2m+2mx}\cdot\frac{(2m-1)+(2m-1)x}{(2m-1)+2mx}\right)\\&=&\sum_{m\geq 1}\log\left(\frac{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2m}\right)x}{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2m-1}\right)x}\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and if we set:
$$ g_m(x) = \log\left(\frac{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2m}\right)x}{1+\left(1+\frac{1}{2m-1}\right)x}\right) $$
we have that over $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have to deal with a decreasing function between:
$$ \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4m^2}\right)\leq g_m(x)\leq 0. $$
Since by the Wallis product:
$$\prod_{m=1}\left(1-\frac{1}{4m^2}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi},$$
we have:
$$\log 2-\log\pi \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n f_n(x) \leq 0 $$
regardless of $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Summing two-by-two is legit since for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$ 0\leq \log\left(1+\frac{x}{n(1+x)}\right)\leq\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n},$$
hence $\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^n f_n(x)\right\}_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Comment: I think you should justify summing them two-by-two. Doing the same approach via the sequence of partial sums would probably be the best way of dealing with this.

Comment: @Jason: ok, I've just added two lines explaining why summing two-by-two is legit.